# How do I find an xml node that does not have an attribute

Tags: python, xml-parsing

I'm using python 2.7 and trying to parse the XML below - what I'm trying to do is create a python array of all genres with a language attribute together with an array where there is no language attribute.

I'm using the python module `import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET`

I know I can find the XML section where the language attribute is in the "fr" language via syntax:

```
tree=ET.ElementTree(file='popups.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for x in root.findall('alt[@{http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace}lang="fr"]/alt'):
   print x.text
```

I dont really understand why I can't use `xml:lang` rather than `{http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace}lang`, but the above seems to work on Ubuntu 12.04

What I'm trying to find out is the "not" syntax - where the XML section does NOT have any language attribute

Anybody have any thoughts how to achieve this?

```
<genre>
  <alt>
        <alt genre="easy listening">lounge</alt>
        <alt genre="alternative">ska</alt>
  </alt>

  <alt xml:lang="fr">
        <alt genre="gospel">catholique</alt>
  </alt>
</genre>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the full QName in your xpath because the stdlib ElementTree does not have a way of registering a prefix. I usually use a helper function to create QNames:

```
def qname(prefix, element, map={'xml':'http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace'}):
    return "{{{}}}{}".format(map[prefix], element)
```

The `ElementTree` implementation in the standard library does not support enough XPath to do what you want easily.  However, the [spec for `xml:lang`](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-lang-tag) specifies that the value of this attribute is inherited by everything that contains it, sort of like `xml:base` or `xmlns` namespace declarations. So as an alternative, we can make the language setting explicit on all elements:

```
xml_lang = qname('xml', 'lang')

def set_xml_lang(root, defaultlang=''):
    xml_lang = qname('xml', 'lang')
    for item in root:
        try:
            lang = item.attrib[xml_lang]
        except KeyError, err:
            item.set(xml_lang, defaultlang)
            lang = defaultlang
        set_xml_lang(item, lang)

set_xml_lang(root)

namespaces = {'xml':'http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace'}
# Every element in root now has an xml:lang attribute
# so XPath is easy now:
alts_with_no_lang = root.findall('alt[@{{{xml}}}lang=""]'.format(**namespaces))
```

If you're willing to use [`lxml`](http://lxml.de), your use of "lang" can be much more robust because it follows the complete XPath 1.0 spec. In particular, you can use the `lang()` function:

```
import lxml.etree as ET

root = ET.fromstring(xml)

print root.xpath('//alt[lang("fr")]')
```

As a bonus, it will have proper `lang()` semantics, like case-insensitivity and being smart about language regions (e.g., `lang('en')` will be true for `xml:lang="en-US"` too).

Unfortunately you can't use `lang()` to determine the language of a node. You need to find the first `xml:lang` ancestor and use that:

```
mylang = node.xpath('(ancestor-or-self::*/@xml:lang)[1]')
```

*Putting it all together*, to match nodes that have no language:

```
tree.xpath('//alt[not((ancestor-or-self::*/@xml:lang)[1])]')
```

Answer (score 1):

> I dont really understand why I can't use xml:lang rather than {http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace}lang, but the above seems to work on Ubuntu 12.04

What you are trying to do will be easier using the `xpath` method (which is *not* available in `cElementTree`), which among other things will read the namespace labels from the root element of your document, so you can ask this:

```
import lxml.etree as et

root = et.parse(open('mydoc.xml')).getroot()

for x in root.xpath('alt[not(@xml:lang)]/alt'):
    print x.text
```

The `not(@attr)` syntax I wasn't previously familiar with, but a Google search for "xpath find element without attribute" was tremendously useful.